# Mailhandler.php need help forms.js

Tags: javascript, php, forms, phpmailer, mailer

Help. I can't send email using xampp. I don't know what to do. I've searched all over the net but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. It seems like they are the same but mine doesn't work. Please take a look at my codes, maybe I just miss something or not based on my understanding. I'm new on sending mails using php. It's my first time to do this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Mailhandler.php

```
    <?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}?>
```

This is the forms.js:

```
;(function($){
$.fn.forms=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this)
            ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'my@email.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true,
                rx:{
                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                    ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.labels.each(function(){
                        var label=$(this),
                            inp=$(_.targets,this),
                            defVal=inp.val(),
                            trueVal=(function(){
                                        var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                        return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                    })()
                        trueVal!=defVal
                            &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                        label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                        inp
                            .bind('focus',function(){
                                inp.val()==defVal
                                    &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            })
                            .bind('blur',function(){
                                _.validateFu(label)
                                if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                    inp.val(defVal)
                                    ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                            })
                            .bind('keyup',function(){
                                label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                    &&_.validateFu(label)
                            })
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                    })
                    _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired:function(el){                            
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid:function(el){                           
                    var ret=true
                    $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                        if(el.is(k))
                            ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                    })
                    return ret                          
                },
                isEmpty:function(el){
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu:function(el){                            
                    el.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                            ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                            ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                            ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                        if(empty&&req)
                            _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        else
                            _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                        if(!empty)
                            if(valid)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel:function(label){
                    var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                        ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                    return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                }
                ,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data:{
                                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })          
                },
                showFu:function(){
                    _.success.slideDown(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        },_.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu:function(){
                    $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click',function(){
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init:function(){
                    _.form=_.me                     
                    _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit',function(){
                            if(_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset',function(){
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
        typeof o=='object'
            &&$.extend(_,o)
    })
} })(jQuery)$(window).load(function(){  
         $('#contact-form').forms({
     ownerEmail:'my@email.com'
     }) })
```

Comment: Do you actually have a mail service running (sendmail, postfix, exim)?  Sending mail via `mail()` is fraught with peril unless you have a deep understanding of how email works (and is junk-filtered, etc), or are at least on a hosted server which already has fully functioning SMTP services.   It is highly recommended to look into something like PHPMailer instead of `mail()`, which makes it easy to configure routing your mail through a 3rd party SMTP http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: Why did you tag this as PHPMailer when you're not using it? You probably should, as doing so is much easier than debugging problems with mail(). Your should get PHPMailer [from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) - the worxware site is long obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am using xampp server an have my smtp server set as localhost.